# Django Help-Take Reg Number from Students & Find out their result

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to build a simple Django app which take Registration number from students and search their result in database and find out their result.

How can I do it? I can't write view.py file for this app. Please help. I'm new to Django.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text



class ResultQuery(models.Model):

    name        =models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dept_name   =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cgpa        =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reg_number  =models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return smart_text(self.name)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms


class ResultForm(forms.Form):

      Reg_No  =forms.CharField(label="Registration Number")
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ResultForm
from .models import ResultQuery



def home(request):

     form=ResultForm(request.POST or None)

     if form.is_valid():

     #How can write queryset here ?


     template_name="Result/home.html"
      context={
          "form":form
         }

      return render(request,template_name,context)
```

## home.html

```
<h1>Search Your Result</h1>

<form method="POST" action=" "> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def home(request):
     form=ResultForm(request.POST or None)
     template_name="Result/home.html"
     context={ "form":form}

     if form.is_valid():
         objects = ResultQuery.objects.filter(reg_number=form.cleaned_data['Reg_No']
         context['objects'] = objects                   


      return render(request,template_name,context)
```

I've filled up the basic but you need to make mods to your template and you also need to check for request method GET/POST in your view.

Comment: Again thanks for your valuable speech & I am trying to follow your instructions.